# Automatically search website field and get resulting URL

Tags: url, web, automation

I want to automatically search a string at http://www.drugbank.ca/ and get the resulting URL (the search field is at the top of the page). The website can't be searched just by manipulating the URL. Is there a server-based way to do this? I want to create my own webpage with an input field and button to "Search DrugBank for X and get the URL".

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that it can't be searched by manipulating the URL? When I search something, the URL contains my query (which you may then change to whatever you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the contents of:

http://www.drugbank.ca/search?query=searchstring

You can't do this with javascript it's not allowed by the browser to query sites of different domains (due to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

I would do it with php and create a file like searchDrugBank.php:

```
<?php
$urlContent = file_get_contents('http://www.drugbank.ca/search?query=' . $_GET['q']);
// process $urlContent however you want
?>
```

And then you put on your site:

```
<form method="get" action="searchDrugBank.php">
<input type="text" name="q" />
<input type="submit" value="Search drugbank"/>
</form>
```

**(Since you asked)**

To find what URL I was gonna query I went to the site, and looked at the form that was submitted when I pressed search (look at the source, or in it's easy to do "inspect element" on for example the searchbox or searchbutton).

I find that the form is:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/search" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>
      <strong>Search:</strong> 
      <input id="query" name="query" placeholder="Search DrugBank" size="30" type="search">
      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Search">&nbsp;
      <a href="/search/advanced">Help / Advanced</a>
</form>
```

Which means that when you press search, exactly what happends is that you will do a **GET** request, since *method="get"* and get request means to ask for an url, and if parameters is required, they should be in the URL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms).

The URL that will be queried is **/search** since action is *action="/search"* the rest of the url will then be built using provided parameters here it's just:

```
<input id="query" name="query" placeholder="Search DrugBank" size="30" type="search">
```

And there you can see that **name** of the parameter that should be provided to do a search, namely **"query"**!

Comment: Thanks. But how did you figure out that you could get a URL containing the search string by adding "search?query=searchstring" to the URL? Is there a method to figure this out?

Comment: I've added that info now, hope you get it. (GET it! haha, get it?)

Comment: That is very interesting! However, what if the method is not _get_ but _post_, and there is no name given? This is the case for the search function on the website [paroles.net](http://www.paroles.net/). It says for the submit ("OK") button: <form class="mlm" action="/search" method="post" id="search-form-round">. The URL always just becomes paroles.net/search after you search something, and I even tried an addon that checks URL redirects and only found that link, but surely there must be a way the actual query is distinguished to the server, right?

Comment: @VincentOostelbos I’d try with a proxy to see exactly what request is made. Or you can’t figure it out by tomorrow I might be able to assist

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, after all these years! I use a proxy addon in Chrome, but I wouldn't know how to use it to see the request that is made. Nevertheless, I will try; if I figure it out, I will let you know here. If not, you can freely assume I did not succeed.

Comment: @VincentOostelbos At paroles.net they're POST'ing the request, with the key `search`. Here's the request https://pastebin.com/EQu0FgsD here's the curl command for sending it https://pastebin.com/t5zjtaQb (Note that you can probably remove a lot of stuff from that CURL command as that's probably tracking stuff).

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand very well what to do with that. I don't know what a CURL command is. Is this related to cURL, client URL? Does that mean I could get a URL from that for a particular search query on that website? If it helps, I am trying to make a DuckDuckGo [bang](https://duckduckgo.com/bang) from this, so I need to find a URL along the lines of `https://store.steampowered.com/search/?term={{{s}}}`, where `{{{s}}}` is where the search query goes.